# Separating vowels and consonants

Tags: ruby, regex

How can you separate vowels and consonants from strings, to create a filter?

How can i replace the consonants and vowels with other letters

I came up with this

```
(\A[^aeio]{1,3})(\w*)/
```

while searching online, but not sure exactly how it works past the filtering part of `^aeio`, to get consonants.

Answer (score 3):

[String.tr](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-tr) is good for transforming text:

```
str = "while searching online, but not sure exactly how it works past the filtering part of ^aeio, to get consonants."
p str.tr('aeiou', '')
#=> "whl srchng nln, bt nt sr xctly hw t wrks pst th fltrng prt f ^, t gt cnsnnts."
p str.tr('^aeiou', '') # the ^ negates
#=>"ieeaioieuoueeaoioaeieiaoaeiooeooa"
p str.tr('aeiou', 'eioua')
#=>"wholi sierchong unloni, bat nut sari ixectly huw ot wurks pest thi foltirong pert uf ^eiou, tu git cunsunents."
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean split like this?

```
1.9.3-p327 > s = "abcqwertyaeiouvbnmi"
 => "abcqwertyaeiouvbnmi"
1.9.3-p327 > s.split(/([aeiou]+)/)
 => ["", "a", "bcqw", "e", "rty", "aeiou", "vbnm", "i"]
```

If so, then you could just loop through the resulting array replacing characters as you go.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "iamagoodboy"
v,c = s.chars.partition{|i| ["a","e","i","o","u"].include?(i)}
p v #=> ["i", "a", "a", "o", "o", "o"]
p c #=> ["m", "g", "d", "b", "y"]
```

Now you can iterate on `v` and `c` as you want.